# Value_counts on multiple columns with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need some help with Pandas.

I have following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1Country': ['FR', 'FR', 'GER','GER','IT','IT', 'FR','GER','IT'],
               '2City': ['Paris', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Berlin', 'Rome', 'Rome','Paris','Berlin','Rome'],
               'F1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
               'F2': ['B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
               'F3': ['C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']})
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kvdb.png)

I am trying to do a `groupby` on first two columns `1Country` and `2City` and do `value_counts` on columns `F1` and `F2`. So far I was only able to do groupby and `value_counts` on 1 column at a time with

```
df.groupby(['1Country','2City'])['F1'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
```

How can I do `value_counts` on multiple columns and get a datframe as a result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `agg`, something along these lines:

```
df.groupby(['1Country','2City']).agg({i:'value_counts' for i in df.columns[2:]})

               F1   F2   F3
FR  Paris  A  2.0  1.0  2.0
           B  1.0  1.0  NaN
           C  NaN  1.0  1.0
GER Berlin A  NaN  2.0  NaN
           B  2.0  1.0  2.0
           C  1.0  NaN  1.0
IT  Rome   B  1.0  1.0  NaN
           C  2.0  2.0  3.0
```

Comment: This answer works even better since I have a lot of columns to work with and using dictionary can be a bit tedious. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a dict to `agg` as follows:

```
df.groupby(['1Country', '2City']).agg({'F1': 'value_counts', 'F2': 'value_counts'})
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!